# how to upload a image,form data into server using httpclient post method?below is my code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code which is taking the data but not uploading a image file.When I am trying its giving error like unsupported content type.

```
public class rest {
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    //HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://community.qa01.xxx.com/api/community/Profile/MyProfile");
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://community.qa01.xxx.com/api/community/Media/UploadImage");
                    //HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://community.qa01.xxx.com/api/community/Group/JoinGroup groupId=4");
                    //request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
                    request.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer xxxxxx");
                    try {
                        //new FileBody(new File("D:\\dummy.jpg"));
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                            try {
                                BufferedReader reader =
                                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                                String line;
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    System.out.println(line);
                                    //JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("response");
                                }
                            } finally {
                                stream.close();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What content type does the web service support?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Content type is application/json.

Comment: I am getting issue like unsupported content-type.Its not giving the image name in data part.

Comment: This is the expected result I am getting when doing manually.
{"StatusCode": 200
"code": 1
"data": "https://communityapi.xxx.telligenthosting.net/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/13-02-00-00-00-04-28-51/Ml82MzU4NjI2MDY1OTM5OTgxMDdfZHVtbXk_3D00_size100x100x.jpg"
"status": "OK"}

But when trying with the above stand alone script the output is:
{"StatusCode":415,"code":-1200,"data":null,"status":"Unsupported ContentType."}

Comment: try without this header `request.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`